# dynamically allocated string populated with characters results in empty string C

Tags: c, string, memory, malloc

```
int main(){
    char *c=(char*)malloc(4*sizeof(char));
    *c='a';
    c++;
    *c='b';
    c++;
    *c='c';
    c++;
    *c='\0';
    printf("%s",c);
    return 0;
}
```

With this code I can print every single character (e.g. `printf("%c",*(--c));` ), but when I try to print the whole string using `printf("%s",c);` the program prints nothing! Why is this happening ?

Comment: You have increased `c` to the last character `'\0'`... So nothing to print.

Comment: When you `printf("%s",c);` `c` points to `\0`

Comment: @Jarod42  Thanks,got it!

Comment: @DimChtz Thanks,got it!

Comment: That really was an error you should have been able to detect yourself (yes, that includes beginners). Next time please use a debugger, single step and watch the variables before asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pointer has been moved. So it is now pointing to the last character which is a "\0". So, nothing is printed. Preserve the pointer in another variable and try to print using that. It will then print correctly.

Try like below:

```
int main()
{
    char *p;
    char *c=(char*)malloc(4*sizeof(char));
    p = c;
    *c='a';
    c++;
    *c='b';
    c++;
    *c='c';
    c++;
    *c='\0';
    printf("%s",p);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

c is a `pointer` and therefore the expression `c++;` changes the pointer location. After calling `c++` 3 times you end up with `c` pointing to `\0`. To fix this issue create a temporary pointer to iterate through the elements. Also you program has a memory leak. Do not forget to `free` the memory!

Answer (score 1):

Because your string is now pointed to last character in allocated string.
Try something like

```
int main(){
    char *c=(char*)malloc(4*sizeof(char));
    char* temp = c;
    *c='a';
    c++;
    *c='b';
    c++;
    *c='c';
    c++;
    *c='\0';
    printf("%s",c); // as a result of ++ operator, your pointer is no longer point at the beginning of string
    printf("%s,temp"); // << This will print whole string as it still pointed to the first address of the string
    free(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

You have increased `c` to the last character `'\0'`... So nothing to print.

You may change your code to:

```
int main(){
    char *p = (char*)malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
    char* c = p;
    *c = 'a';
    c++;
    *c = 'b';
    c++;
    *c = 'c';
    c++;
    *c = '\0';
    printf("%s", p);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
int main(){
    char *c = (char*)malloc(4 * sizeof(char));

    c[0] = 'a';
    c[1] = 'b';
    c[2] = 'c';
    c[3] = '\0';
    printf("%s", c);
    free(c);
    return 0;
}
```